# How can I read input while it exists?

Tags: c++, scanf, eof

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
int main(){
    char s = ' ';
    while (s != NULL)
    {
        scanf ("%c", &s);
        int a = 0;
            if (s == '"')
            {
                if (a == 0) printf("``");
                    else printf("''");
                a = 1- a;

            }
            else
                printf("%c", s);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

this is my code, I'm new in C++, I'm writing this for uva.onlinejudge.org. the input is some text that we don't know it's size. I wanted to know how to get input while it exists ( I tried s != NULL but the program doesn't stop and gets the last char for ever)

Comment: Your question is tagged C++, so there are a lot of ways to do this. However, is there a specific reason you're using C-style IO?

Comment: Belongs on http://debug-my-code-for-me.com

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about asking for free debugging

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>

// ...

while ( std::cin.get(s) )
{
    // your code goes here
}
```

BTW in your existing code, `scanf` should be `std::scanf`, etc. The standard functions are all in the `std::` namespace, and may or may not also be found in the global namespace.

Comment: Are you sure it should generate a warning? While the standard requires symbols declared in the standard library to be in the `std` namespace, it does not forbid them from also appearing in the global namespace. Two of the most implementations do precisely this. I don't think either of them warn about using those functions.

Comment: You're right, C++11 `[headers]#4` has text explicitly permitting the names to also appear in global namespace (actually, it is unspecified whether or not they do). I'm not sure if C++98 had that text.